# Is it possible to be awarded damages in a First Amendment case?

Tags: constitutional-law, first-amendment, freedom-of-religion

The case is a de facto promotion of religion by a local municipality.

A private citizen has placed a religiously promotive flyer on the notices board at the department of a local municipality. The board is enclosed by a locked, plexiglass window, and it is to the outside of this window the flyer has been taped.

While not responsible for putting it up, after about 2 months of it being there with staff able to see it 7 days a week, standing next to it, posting official notices, they have "adopted" it and are now liable for its presence. I say three days was sufficient time to be responsible in removal.

I plan on waiting until it's removed by anyone before filing a complaint and suit just so it's as huge as possible, exposing their negligence, "sticking it to them" for the schadenfreude, but I wonder if there's any personal damages to possibly be awarded, or -- as I suspect -- would it all be in the form of contributions to secular, church-state separation organizations and having to allow every other type of religious and areligious promotion for an equal amount of time?

Answer (score 6):

In a civil rights action in which someone prevails (which is by no means certain in this case, but not impossible either), there is at a minimum an award of nominal damages (i.e. $1) and the reasonable attorney fees and litigation costs incurred in the lawsuit.

A jury could also award a prevailing party non-economic damages, and/or exemplary damages (a.k.a punitive damages) in connection with a violation of civil rights.

There might also be injunctive or declaratory relief stating that this was a violation of civil rights and requiring the government to adopt practices to prevent harm going forward.

It is hard to see how there would be any economic damages at issue in this case, but it isn't impossible to imagine some circumstances in which they could be proven, perhaps.

Comment: Of course, all this assumes the plaintiff wins the case, which seems awfully unlikely on the facts presented.

Comment: In the unlikely event that the plaintiff succeeds, and in the unlikely event that damages were awarded, it seems to me they would be reduced to nominal given *"I plan on waiting until it's removed by anyone before filing a complaint"* as the defendant would argue that they would have removed the notice had anyone complained.

Comment: If a jury finds in your favor, it frequently imposes compensatory and/or exemplary damages.